Is this horse hair plaster salveagable?
Our 1911 Home has a 14x13 room with what looks like compromised horse hair plaster on lath. The plaster looks to be around 3/8" thick.

Would you strip this down to the studs and start over with drywall? We are having MassSave do high density cellulose blow-in from the exterior for the whole house next month.
If we tried to salvage it, would we have to cut out the parts with no structure and replace with 3/8" sheetrock?





I think I would just slap drywall over the plaster.  If you can find and mark the studs then can use longer screws, or can glue the drywall to the plaster.

I read somewhere that horsehair plaster can contain asbestos,  and it can also contain anthrax ... have it tested

Totally salvageable. Anyone wants to rip that out, they're trying to charge you to hang drywall instead of just a patch and a skim coat.

I ended up cutting out the parts that no longer were keyed to the lath and used structo-lite to re-key against the lath as the basecoat, and now I'm planning to use EasySand 90 with Fiberglass tape between the base coat and finish coat.

I wouldn't bother trying to fix century-old plaster. If parts of it are crumbling now, then other parts will follow soon. So that leaves two options:

Strip the wall down to the studs and install drywall. If you're having people blowing insulation into the wall, then talk to them first. They may have some thoughts on what order to do everything in.
Put thin drywall (like 1/2") over the plaster.

I can see pros and cons to both approaches.

I can see that a con with #2 is that even a 1/4" drywall over the plaster will be above the trim ridges, but I was going to remove that mid-line trim anyways. Also I heard that if the drywall doesn't catch the studs well, the screws can pop off or cause a cupping affect over time to the drywall. What other cons can you think of?

You'll have to move the light switch out a 1/4", along with any other electric fixtures that aren't shown in the photos.

Not sure what you mean by "catching the studs well". Drywall has to be tightly attached to the studs, that's true no matter how you install it.
